# Zooming doesn't work in Unity although FOV changes

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, zooming

I am working on a 2D project and I want to zoom in my map by scrollwheel. I am sure that my code is working (because during the play mode, field of view changes when scrollwheel is rotated) but no change on the screen is observed.

Besides, during play mode even if I change the field of view manually (from the editor), the screen view remains same. That is, although field of view is observed to be seen changing but the screen view is not.

What are the possible reasons for that?

Here is the screenshot of the editor attached:

[image]

Comment: I still suggest you to post your code here, it'll improve this question's chances to be answered.

Comment: The simple way of thinking about it is, when you change your field of view your cone gets smaller, the end results of that cone are essentially stretch to take up your screen space.  a game with a resolution of 1024x768 with a field of view 90 vs a game resolution of 1024x768 with a field of view 45, still has the same amount of screenspace.  The UI elements in Unity use screenspace when drawn they are not placed into the actual game world.  Unless you specifically place them into world space.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because you're using screen space canvas. Put the canvas in the world space for field of view to have any effect.

Comment: and maybe consider changing the projection of the camera to orthographic since you making a 2d game